# Searching %LIKE% in a result of records without sql

Tags: php, mysql, elasticsearch, sphinx

Im using an ORM - Eloquent for my db queries.
I have a table with 17M records and 4 indexes in there.
Everything is fine and fast.
However I have 6-7 fields that are VARCHAR and needs to be searched with %LIKE%.
Basically the steps are:
1.Search the 17M table by indexes and retrieve about 20k rows.
2.From that result search a single string into all record's fields and return the ones which success.

The question is what to be used for step 2 for best performance and realization.
Im thinking of using sphinx or elastic search but dont know how fast its going to be.

Comment: anybody ? is elastics be ok for the pourpose

Comment: Yes, using a full-text engine will probably work. Maybe even inbuilt mysql Full-text support. As to which is *best* is largely subjective and a matter of taste (and even server capablities). Its upto you to pick, nobody else is qualified to pick **for** you.

Comment: definitely elastic is the best choice looking the amount of the data you have.

Comment: Elasticsearch is built for searching, so if you are looking for something to search tons of records, then...kind of explains itself.  One might tailor to your tech stack better, but in general, ES is the better option.